# Gmail LodgingReservation Email Markup doesn't work

Tags: google-schemas

I try to use LodgingReservation Markup.

Documentation says that I can send email from own gmail mailbox to the same mailbox for testing.

I prepared simple test email:

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "LodgingReservation",
          "reservationNumber": "abc456",
          "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
          "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "John Smith"
          },
          "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
            "name": "Hilton San Francisco Union Square",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "333 O'Farrell St",
              "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
              "addressRegion": "CA",
              "postalCode": "94102",
              "addressCountry": "US"
            },
            "telephone": "415-771-1400"
          },
          "checkinDate": "2027-04-11T16:00:00-08:00",
          "checkoutDate": "2027-04-13T11:00:00-08:00"
        }
        </script>
    test
</body>
</html>
```

Email markup Tester can parse it successfully. But when I send the email and check it in my Inbox, it doesn't show card with reservation's information.

Origin message:

```
Return-Path: <kaba.nitesoft@gmail.com>
Received: from MSI ([90.189.151.28])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id q16-20020a2e84d0000000b0025e71cdb753sm287017ljh.46.2022.08.09.23.49.57
        for <kaba.nitesoft@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 09 Aug 2022 23:49:58 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <62f35516.2e0a0220.3adbf.15f2@mx.google.com>
Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2022 23:49:58 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Original-Date: 10 Aug 2022 13:49:58 +0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: kaba.nitesoft@gmail.com
To: kaba.nitesoft@gmail.com
Subject: Confirmation
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

What is wrong? How I can test markup correctly?

Another question:

If email contains attached receipt in pdf-format, Gmail shows reservation's card by parsed data from attached file. It's problem that Gmail parses it incorrectly (for instance it shows incorrect CheckoutDate). So, can I disable this behavior? Or how I can format pdf document that it will be parsed correctly?